# Splash Screen with flutter_native_splash

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, flutter-native

⚠️ The parameter "android 12" was found in your flutter_native_splash config, but "android 12" is not a valid flutter_native_splash parameter.

i will try to use the flutter_native_splash with the version is  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.7 but this will give me the error of --> ankit@Dhattarwal-Air fluom % dart run flutter_native_splash:create --path=splash.yaml
Building package executable...
Built flutter_native_splash:create.
⚠️ The parameter "android 12" was found in your flutter_native_splash config, but "android 12" is not a valid flutter_native_splash parameter.
ankit@Dhattarwal-Air fluom %

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple typo.

flutter_native_splash config yaml is named `android_12:`, you got a space instead of an underscore.

Refer here, in "Usage" section: [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)